# Android AppWidget ListView element height doesn't wrap content

Tags: android, listview

I am building an app widget using `ListView` with `RemoteViewsFactory`, everything is working good but I have one problem, my list rows doesn't wrap content, for example if elements are images, they fit the row space, but if I have only text views there is a lot of empty space between the view and the end of the row. For parent layout ListView `layout_height` is `wrap_content` and for the custom element inside list I have such a layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_txt1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_border"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_txt2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@color/md_red_900" />
</LinearLayout>
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you're using "weight" the width should be 0dp on the TextViews.

Comment: yes, but this is not the main problem in my case

Comment: You should set WeightSum to 3 I think.